# How to change color depending on what is returned in a view?

Tags: css, angularjs, html, sass

I have a div which returns a different status like the following:

- Sold
- On demand
- Not paid
- Overdue
- Paid

I would like to have a different color for each status using sass or css,

This is what I have tried using sass :

In HTML view:

```
<div class="badge">
    {{store.status | translate | uppercase}}
</div>
```

In stylesheet:

```
$status : sold, paid, notpaid, on demand;

@else if($status == sold){
   .badge{
      color: red;
   }
}

@else if ($status == paid){
    .badge{
       color: green;
    }
]
@else if($status == returned{
   .badge{
       color: blue;
   }
]
@else if ($status == notpaid{
   .badge{
      color: yellow;
   }
}
else{
  .badge{
    color : black;
}
```

This does not work. Can someone please help with the best way to achieve what I want?

NOTE: Status is dynamically returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do this.

```
<div class="badge {{store.status}}">
    {{store.status | translate | uppercase}}
</div>
```

And in the SASS have:

```
.badge{
   &.sold{
      background-color: red;
   }
   &.notpaid{
      background-color: green;
   }
   &.paid{
      background-color: blue,
   }
}
```

It’s not possible to get the value in the Sass file.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0cm19uec/

Comment: remember those data are not static are returned dynamically in a view ,

Comment: Now I put and example ... I forgot the $ in the Sass.

Answer (score 1):

SASS doesn't quite work like that. You need to add a class to your badge for that to work properly. Something like this:

```
<div class="badge {{store.status}}">
    {{store.status | translate | uppercase}}
</div>
```

Sass:

```
.badge {
    .notpaid {
        color: yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: please read carefully my question i have one class which return different status in a table its list  eg in a table u have a car with status sold assume u have manny cars wuth different status , paid, not paid, sold, broken, etc etc , so I want each status to contain different color hope u got me , thanks

Comment: My example would repeat the returned status as a class for the badge div, which you could then reference in your SASS. You are attempting to use some sort of dynamic if statements in your stylesheet, which is not how CSS works.

Comment: Your right but still your method  does not work though :(

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this.

**SCSS**

```
$statuses: (
  sold: red,
  paid: green,
  notpaid: yellow,
  demand: blue
);

.badge {
  color: black;

  @each $name, $value in $statuses {
    &--#{$name} {
      color: $value;
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="badge"></div><!--black-->
<div class="badge badge--sold"></div><!--red-->
<div class="badge badge--paid"></div><!--green-->
<div class="badge badge--notpaid"></div><!--yellow-->
<div class="badge badge--demand"></div><!--blue-->

<div class="badge badge--{{store.status | translate | lowercase}}"></div>
```

Its a lot easier to maintain if you ever need to change your classes, add new ones, change colours, etc. Its all done in the **$statuses** map.

Comment: hii @gavin remember its a loop which have just one class nmed <div class="badge">{store.status}} </div> this div retun different status in a column like table eg u have car1 car2 car3 and echa have different status sold, paid , not paid, etc what i need is each of returned status must have its own color . eg car1 status(sold) color green, car2 status(notpaid) color red etc etc.

Comment: @HotZellah Thats cool. My answer is similar to the accepted answer.